# Timestamp Column in Hive to be slabbed based on minutes section

Tags: hive, hiveql

We have lots of csv files with millions of data that are being pushed into Hive External Table by merging 12 files as a single file and then feeding the data to machine learning team.

CSV file is the raw file which has Phonenumber, Col1,Col2.....Created_date.

The Merge of 12 csv files into one csv huge csv file is loaded into Hive External Table.

So the fields we want to fetch are Phonenumber,Created_date(Timestamp)

Time stamp should be written in time slot/ time slab basing on hh:mm ( excluding date part and seconds part)

FOr example if the hh:mm falls in 00:00 to 00:15 it should write 1, similarly if it falls in 00:15 to 00:30 it should write 2....23:45 to 00:00 whould write 96.

So final result should look like 
PhoneNo | TimeSlot/Slab
9999999|  1
8888888|  23
...

Thanks in Advance friends

Venkat

Comment: (1) The question is not clear (2) It seems you have a wrong conception about what external table is

Comment: Hi Mark, have edited my query above.

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (select timestamp '2017-03-23 22:47:01' as Created_date) 
select (hour(Created_date)*60 + minute(Created_date)) div 15 + 1 
from t
```

> 92

Comment: Hi Mark !! Thanks for the quicky :) I shall check this and let you know !!